# How to iteratively expand nodes (on clicking) using popoto.js?

Tags: neo4j, graph-visualization

I am developing a web interface to the neo4j database using popoto.js. Currently, I am able to display a start node and expand the graph up to 3-4 levels by clicking on the node relationships. It seems that the underlying query that popoto uses gets updated along with the expanding graph and after a certain point the query becomes invalid and popoto resets the graph. What I am trying to create is an interface where I can expand any node in the graph (and hence expanding the overall graph) similar to what is possible in the neo4j browser. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should probably create a new [popoto.js issue](https://github.com/Nhogs/popoto/issues).

Comment: I have created an issue but haven't received any comments yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popoto.js handles this automatically but the schema has to be defined in the following way to assist it.

```
export const schema = {
    Person: {
        label: "Person",
        value: {
            name: ""
        },
        rel: [
            {
                label: "works_at",
                target: {
                    label: "company",
                },
            },
            {
                label: "studies_at",
                target: {
                    label: "college",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    Company: {
        label: "company",
        value: {
            name: ""
        },
        rel: [
            {
                label: "works_at",
                target: {
                    label: "person",
                },
            }
        ]
    }
    }
```